# Footer as parallax

Tags: css

I need to create a footer that acts as a parallax. It has to be at the bottom of the page and when a user scrolls to the bottom, footer overlaps the content.

For now I understand that I have to use position fixed, but then the footer is attached to the `viewport` but I need it to stay at the bottom of the page.

Here is what I have:

```
<style>
main{
position:relative;
z-index:1
}

footer{
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: #7dc6ff;
    top: 50px; left: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}
</style>

<main>
Content of the page
</main>
<footer>
footer
</footer>
```

Here is a little picture of what I need. Footer is at the bottom and when scrolled to the bottom footer overlaps content like parallax https://ibb.co/yQS03Xb.

Comment: Davis please can you upload the image again, the format is not supported I think.

Comment: @Rex5 Sorry...added new link

Comment: if i am right, you want footer always fixed in the bottom?

Comment: @SunilRajput always at the bottom of the page. Not sticked to the viewport

Comment: @Pete Any suggestions how exactly?

Comment: @Davis can u please described me more?

Comment: @SunilRajput I need the footer to be as in most websites to the bottom of the page. However when you scroll to the bottom footer has to overlap page content. Check the link I attached

Comment: just found by google. might help you. http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/YhLQr/

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-attachment: fixed;` property on footer

Comment: I think this is the property of CSS if anyone know's CSS he can use this property in his style sheet inside some specific class  "

if it still need clarification its simple footer{background-attachment: fixed;}"

Comment: I've meant to explain, ***why*** will this code work.